# Download images using selenium sequentially using multiple chromes

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code of trying to download 10 images each sequentially from each chrome,

I need to download 10 images each sequentially from each chrome window as for example the first chrome will download from 1-10 and second from 11-20 and in this way the 10th chrome can download from 91-100 sequentially.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var b = 0;


        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {

        //var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        //chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl");
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        element.SendKeys("elon musk jpeg");
        element.Submit(); 

        var i = 0;


            IList<IWebElement> Imghref = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rg_i"));


            foreach (IWebElement eachLink in Imghref)
            {
                eachLink.Click();
                i++;
                b++;
                IWebElement Image = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("v4dQwb"));



                IWebElement img = Image.FindElement(By.ClassName("n3VNCb"));



                String base64String = img.GetAttribute("src");

                string ImageName = img.GetAttribute("alt");

                Console.WriteLine("Image URL : " + base64String);

                String converted = base64String.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", string.Empty);
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
                File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\VisualStudio Workspace\\task\\images\\image" + b + ".jpg", bytes);

                if (i == 10)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        
    }
```

The issue is that how can i use foreach loop variable to continue from the image used by the last chrome which is being downloaded before?

Comment: You need to compare the names in "IList<IWebElement>" with previous downloaded files and then filter the IList to remove files already downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're looking for with [nunit test cases](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcase.html)

The concept will be that you can parallel run all tests in your class and define the input and output boundaries.
For example:  *(without just copying most of your code)*

```cs
[TestCase(0, 9)]
[TestCase(10, 19)]
[TestCase(20, 29)]
//...etc...
[TestCase(90, 99)]

public void yourClass(int start, int end)
{

//potentially 2 lines to change:

//for i, use your requested starting point
     var i = start;


//end when you reach the end:
    if (i == end)
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

Information on how to then parallel run these test case [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution.html)

***Disclaimer** - I've not had chance to run this - Purpose is to guide you on an approach*

---

**UPDATE**

I tried it with a simple write line.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Threading;
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]

namespace StackTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ParallelTest
    {
        [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
        [Test]
        [TestCase(0,9)]
        [TestCase(10, 19)]
        [TestCase(20, 29)]
        public void Run(int Start, int end)
        {
            for(int i =Start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " -> "+ DateTime.Now);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Outputs this (note the times are the same)

```
NUnit Adapter 4.0.0.0: Test execution started
   NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 3 of 3 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Non-Explicit run
10 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:57
11 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:58
12 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:59
13 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:00
14 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:01
15 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:02
16 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:03
17 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:04
18 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:05
19 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:06

20 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:57
21 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:58
22 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:59
23 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:00
24 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:01
25 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:02
26 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:03
27 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:04
28 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:05
29 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:06

0 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:57
1 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:58
2 -> 14/07/2021 16:31:59
3 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:00
4 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:01
5 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:02
6 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:03
7 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:04
8 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:05
9 -> 14/07/2021 16:32:06
```